# C++ variable argument error

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions

I stumbled across a weird behaviour in MSVC (2013) recently which I wanted to clarify concerning variable arguments.

It appears having more than one parameter before the '...)' causes unexpected behaviour

```
int formatString(const char* msg, char* buffer, int bufferLength, ...)
{
    int length = 0;
    if (msg != nullptr) {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, msg);
        length = vsnprintf_s(buffer, bufferLength, bufferLength, msg, args);
        va_end(args);
    }

    return length;
}
```

Calling this function like so

```
const char* message = "A word: %s and a number %d";
const int bufferLength = 1024;
char buffer[bufferLength];
int formattedMsgLen = formatString(message, buffer, bufferLength, "cheese", 4);
```

Will immediately cause the program to crash. If I memset the buffer to 0 before

```
memset(buffer, 0, 1024); // We know sizeof(char) == 1
```

This is written to the buffer:

```
"A word: A word:  and a number 1024".
```

Which is completely wrong...

If however, I change the function to take a struct with the first three arguments combined

```
struct Message
{
    const char* msg;
    char* buffer;
    int bufferLength;
};

int formatString(Message msg, ...)
{
    int length = 0;
    if (msg.msg != nullptr) {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, msg);
        length = vsnprintf_s(msg.buffer, msg.bufferLength, msg.bufferLength, msg.msg, args);
        va_end(args);
    }

    return length;
}
```

When calling the new function like so:

```
const int bufferLength = 1024;
char buffer[bufferLength];
Message msg;
msg.buffer = buffer;
msg.msg = "A word: %s and a number %d";
msg.bufferLength = bufferLength;
int formattedMsgLen = formatString(msg, "cheese", 4);
```

This is written to the buffer:

```
"A word: cheese and a number 4"
```

Which is correct and this is what I would expect. Am I right in thinking you are only able to use vaargs with a function with only one parameter before? I don't think this is the case as the functions below have more than one first parameter

```
int fprintf(FILE *, const char *fmt, ...);
int sprintf(char *s, const char *fmt, ...);
```

Could this potentially be a bug in the compiler? However unlikely....

It probably isn't and I've done something stupid but I am definitely confused by what is happening. If anyone can shed some light on this I would be very grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`va_start()` must be called with the name of the *last* parameter before the variable argument list:

```
int formatString(const char* msg, char* buffer, int bufferLength, ...)
{
    // ...

    va_list args;
    // va_start(args, msg);   <-- WRONG!
    va_start(args, bufferLength); 

    // ...
}
```

Comment: To be specific, it causes undefined behaviour to call `va_start` with the wrong parameter.